# Bootstrap Carousel - Mobile Touch Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have sections of a responsive site that cycle through text and images with bootstrap carousel. The problem is that when someone was testing the site, they could not swipe up and down to view more of the website. They would get the the *Services* section on their iPad then click and drag to scroll either up and down, but were unable to. I believe it's because of the swipe compatibility which works left and right but it's causing the user to be unable to swipe up and down to scroll.

So basically, is there a way to disable vertical swiping so when it takes up 100% of the mobile page size then they can point and drag with their finger to scroll up and/or down on touch screens?

You can view the site, specifically the *Services* section, to see what I'm talking about.

*removed the site*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change one parameter in jquery.elastislide.js on line 13:

```
from
preventDefaultEvents: true

to
preventDefaultEvents: false
```

Comment: Hi, did you fix that?